# Splunk sort -> streamstats very slow on 100s millions of events

Tags: splunk

I have a *simplified* query below that's bottlenecked on the `sort 0 start_time` statement (I think) since I have 100s of millions of events to process.

```
...
| sort 0 start_time
| streamstats current=t first(start_time) by id
...
```

Theoretically speaking, I don't need to sort **all** the events by start_time.

I only need the events to be sorted by `start_time` within each group of events with the same `id`.

So if I could get Splunk to first build a hashtable on `id`, it could then use that hashtable to group the `id`s, then sort by `start_time` within each group. This would be much faster I think.

Note: Each group (by `id`) contains between 1-10 events, which is why sorting within each group rather than sorting all events would be much faster.

Is there a way I could this? Or an alternative approach entirely?

## EDIT

Thanks for the comment @charlie. Maybe this can be done with just `stats`

Here's the simplified structure of my events:

```
id: str
n: int
start: timestamp
end: timestamp
```

Within each `id` group, I need:

1. the min `start`
2. the max `end`
3. the sum of `n`
4. the value of `n` associated with the event that has the min `start` (as in point 1. above)

I have a starting point here:

```
| stats min(start), max(end), sum(n) by id
```

but I'm missing (4.) as mentioned above. How could I get that?

Comment: Yes, sorting tons of events (and large events with lots of fields) can take a lot of time and resources.

I think the bigger question is what are you doing with the events after this point...do you need all of the events? or only certain fields from the events? 

If you're only interested in the smallest start time for each id, `| stats min(start_time) by id` and no sorting required and very minimal data back required from indexers... but  then what?

Comment: Hi @Charlie, true I think this might be possible with `stats`, but I'm missing one piece. I updated my question with an EDIT section below the original.

Comment: Feels like something that should be easy but I'm totally stuck on point 4.

Comment: Ok figured out a hack to pull it off

Comment: `| eventstats min(start) as start_min by id 
| eval mask=IF(start==start_min, 0.0, 1.0)
| stats min(start), max(end), sum(eval(mask*n)) by id` This allows me to exclude the value of `n` associated with the event that has the min `start` from the total sum in `n_sum`, which was exactly what I needed. Feels hacky.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: the `earliest` / `earliest_time` stats functions might be helpful :)

If your data is ingested such that start is being parsed into the _time field then:

```
| stats min(start) max(end) sum(n) earliest(n) by id
```

I have a lingering thought memory coming out of the back of my head that events need to be in _time order for the `earliest` and `earliest_time` functions to work... But [it's not mentioned in the docs](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Timefunctions#earliest.28X.29)

and playing on my test stack with makeresults and random seems to be doing ok, so I wonder if your events don't use start as _time, then assuming your start field is in Unix epoch time format...

```
| eval _time = start
| stats min(start) max(end) sum(n) earliest(n) by id
```

Because of the eval `min(start)` should be the same as `earliest_time(n)` IF all events with id and start (_time) field also have an `n` field, Otherwise you may need a `| fillnull n` before the stats as well.